# run/go hell for leather (informal not polite to run as fast as possible)

Tags: idioms

run/go hell for leather
*informal not polite* to run as fast as possible

https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/run-go-hell-for-leather

Any people know why 'leather' stands here?

run(we know it's action moving our legs fast back and forth), hell(it's like 'fuck' a kind of seasoning slang), for(as 'toward' or as 'for the sake of'), and leather (why the noun leather is here)

Comment: _Hell_ is not an expletive here, it's just part of the expression.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that "leather" in the expression hell-for-leather originally referred to a horse's saddle and tack, as the expression was first used when talking about riding a horse as fast as possible. It first occurs in print in Rudyard Kipling's "The Valley of the Shadow" from 1889:

> CAPT. M. (Jealously) Then don’t say it! Leave him alone. It’s not bad enough to croak over. Here, Gaddy, take the chit to Bingle and ride hell-for-leather. It’ll do you good. I can’t go.
> JUNIOR CHAPLAIN. (Flicking M.’s charger.) That’ll do, thanks. Turn in, Gadsby, and I’ll bring Bingle back–ahem–‘hell-for-leather.’

Comment: [This Google Books search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hell+for+leather%22&biw=1508&bih=703&sxsrf=ALeKk00bh0h8dtESRlSJ0A5iY6wFsJU8PA%3A1621865104171&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1800%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1890&tbm=bks) finds two written instances from well before Kipling's (one's from 1843, the other from 1879).